# ASP.NET MVC application controller constructor problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've created an application controller abstract class that my controllers derive from (As described in the following [article](http://www.asp.net/Learn/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx))

The following is an example of what my code looks like

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    private ProjectDataContext datacontext = new ProjectDataContext();

    protected ProjectDataContext DataContext
    {
        get { return datacontext; }
    }

    public ApplicationController()
    {
        ViewData["OpenTasks"] = DataContext.Tasks.Where(t => t.UserId == this.UserId).Count();
    }
}
```

This produces the following error which i have determined is due to the "Where" lamda expression:

***If the controller doesn't have a controller factory, ensure that it has a parameterless public constructor.***

this error is produced whichever way i write the LINQ query and the only way to compile the application is by removing the "Where" clause as follows.

```
ViewData["OpenTasks"] = DataContext.Tasks.Count();
```

any ideas what the problem is or how to resolve this as i need to execute the query against the user and not return all entries.

thanks in advance

Comment: Show implementation of UserId property

Answer (score 10):

Try this instead of using the constructor:-

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    private ProjectDataContext datacontext = new ProjectDataContext();

    protected ProjectDataContext DataContext
    {
        get { return datacontext; }
    }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(RequestContext);
        ViewData["OpenTasks"] = DataContext.Tasks.Where(t => t.UserId == this.UserId).Count();
    }
}
```

Its quite likely that the current user ID is dependand on the RequestContext

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the call is crashing in the constructor because the UserId (this.UserId) hasn't been initialised yet.